# how to animate a Bitmap image with motion in android

Tags: android

> Score is a drawable image

```
private Bitmap Scores;
private boolean running =true;
private SurfaceView mySurfaceHolder;
Scores.decodeResource(myContext.getResource(), R.drawable.score);

//this is just the run procedure
@Override 
public void onRun()
{
   while(running){

       Canvas c = null;
     try{
         c = mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
              synchronize(mySurfaceHolder){           
                        drawScore(c);  //here is where i call my method..
              }
      }finally{
         mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

  }
```

}

```
  //the pontsGain and onTitle are both boolean variables so please don't get confuse
  //and pointScoreAtY is an integer that will allocate my specific position in screen
  private void drawScore(Canvas c)
  {
      try{
          if(pointsGain && !onTitle)
        {
              pointScoreAtY = (int)(FingerY -(Scores.getHeight()/2)-100);

              int i=100;
            do{
            try{

                c.drawBitmap(Scores, (FingerX -(Scores.getWidth()/2))+200,pointScoreAtY, null);
                invalidate();
                 pointScoreAtY -=i;

            }catch(Exception e){}
            }while(i-->0);
            pointsGain = false;
        }
      }catch(Exception e){}
  }
```

> This specific function is drawing a bitmap into the screen at current location but it is not what i am looking to do... for example my main goal is when a character on my game gets hit i want to show a scorePoint and animate it so that it can go up and disappear from screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add animation to your imageview like this:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    view.startAnimation(anim);
```

For more animation details check android developer site:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html